# Show $ \langle 5,7 \rangle $ and $ \langle 6,9 \rangle $ are principal ideals in $\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Show $ \langle 5,7 \rangle $ and $ \langle 6,9 \rangle $ are principal ideals in $\Bbb Z$ .

I don't understand what the difference between a principal ideal and an ideal is?

I need some tips on this question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain, there's no difference in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You need to show that there exists some number $a$ so that 
$$\langle5,7\rangle =\langle a\rangle.$$

**Hint 2:** Try $a=\gcd(5,7)$. To prove the equality of ideals use double inclusion.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: @PatrickStevens Ty :)

Comment: oh so you mean <1> right ? This question was easy after all ...

Comment: and for 6 9 we can use <3> or <1> ?

Comment: @ggok Is $\langle 6, 9 \rangle = \langle 1 \rangle$? Is it even the case that $\langle 6, 9 \rangle \supseteq \langle 1 \rangle$?

Comment: no u are right i didnt think about it :)

Comment: How would i go about to show <1> is includedd in <5,7> I tried forming an equation 5x+7y=c but i cant prove that this always has an integer solution

Comment: @ggok Use the extended euclidian algorithm. Or use the fact that $1=21-20$.

Answer (score 2):

A principal ideal is one with a single generator. You may be familiar with the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain (because it is a Euclidean domain): every ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ is principal.

However, invoking that theorem is probably against the spirit of the question. So you're going to need to find a single integer $n$ such that $\langle n \rangle = \langle 5,7\rangle$. Since $5 \in \langle n\rangle$, we must have $n \mid 5$; and since $7 \in \langle n \rangle$, we must have $n \mid 7$.

Now, once you've found your candidate $n$, show that it works: show that everything in $\langle 5,7\rangle$ is in $\langle n \rangle$, and that everything in $\langle n \rangle$ is in $\langle 5,7\rangle$.